# Need to implement confirmation box in grails

Tags: jquery, grails, button, popup

I need to implement a confirmation message box in grails when I press the stop button. The code for my stop button is

```
<a class="stopimg" href="${createLink(controller: 'Test', action: 'Stop', id: i.Id)}">&nbsp;Stop&nbsp;</a>
```

I have the confirmation message box created as well.

```
<div id="popup_box2">
  <div class="popup-warapper">
    <form name="">
      <div class="popup-title"><a id="popupBoxClose2" class="popup-close"><img alt="close" src="images/close.png"></a>
        <div class="title">Confirmation</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="popup-content">
        <div>Are you sure you want to Stop the server?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons"> <span>
        <input class="popupBtn" type="button" value="Yes" name="stop_service" id="stop_service" />
        <input class="popupBtn" type="button" value="No" name="none" id="none" />
        </span> </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am loading this in my head

```
        $('.stopimg').click(function(){
    // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
    loadPopupBox2();
    });

        $('#popupBoxClose2').click( function() {            
        unloadPopupBox2();
    });

function loadPopupBox2() {  // To Load the Popupbox
        $('#popup_box2').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#popup_box2').css({ "left":(screen.width/2)-(285/2)});
        $("#mainWrapper").css({ // this is just for style
            "opacity": "0.3"  
        });
    }

        function unloadPopupBox2() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
        $('#popup_box2').fadeOut("slow");
        $("#mainWrapper").css({ // this is just for style
            "opacity": "1"  
        });
    }
```

I need to link this somehow to my stop button.  If i use html button the code is working but when I am using it in grails it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick handler to the yes button.

```
$('.stopimg').click(function(){
    $("#stop_service").attr("onclick", "window.location.href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "';");
    loadPopupBox2();
});

$('#popupBoxClose2').click( function() {            
    $("#stop_service").removeAttr("onclick");
    unloadPopupBox2();
});
```

Comment: That sentence made 0 sense. (He deleted the comment)

Comment: Ok here, <a class="stopimg" href="${createLink(controller: 'Test', action: 'Stop', id: i.Id)}">&nbsp;Stop&nbsp;</a>, This is what is causing the issue. Instead of this if i use, <input type="button" class="stopimg" name="stop" id="stop1" value="Stop" />, The popup shows up.

Comment: Add `onclick="return false;"` to your anchor tag